# Bind input to 2 variables with one getting updated through ng-model-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to bind 2 Angular model variables to a range input element according to the following:

- update first model variable for every change of the range input
- update second model variable after x ms of the last range input
  change / on blur using `ng-model-options`

The first model variable is used to display the current range value in a label element.

The second model variable is used to trigger UI updates. To prevent slowness, it therefore has to be updated less often.

Does someone know how to do that?

Code for input and label elements where the first model variable is `rangeIndex`.

```
<input id="range-slider" type="range" min="0" max="{{rangeList.length-1}}" ng-model="rangeIndex">

<label for="range-slider">{{rangeList[rangeIndex] | range}}</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind 2 variables to a single input. If you need such behavior, you should consider the following solution:

1. Create a getter/setter and use then in the options ([see example here](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/ngmodeloptions-total-model-control)).
2. Define a debounced function using lodash _.debounce.
3. In your getter/setter, update the relevant value and invoke the debounced method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are going for, but it sounds like you want to have a slider. Then you'll show the current value on the screen somewhere, and then after x ms update the UI. I put together a fiddle which should give you something to model your code after. If the fiddle doesn't quite answer your question, let me know whats wrong and Ill update it.

Here's a snippet of the controller code:

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$timeout',function($scope, $timeout){

    $scope.rangeList = {
        0:'00',
        1:'11',
        2:'22',
        3:'33'
    };

    // create a default, blank timer
    var timer = $timeout(function(){}, 0);

    $scope.changeRange = function(){

        // always clear old timer
        $timeout.cancel(timer);

        // start a new one
        timer = $timeout(function(){
            $scope.updateUI();
        }, 1000);
    };

    $scope.updateUI = function(){
        $scope.updatedRange = $scope.rangeList[$scope.rangeIndex];
    }

}]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gu9fm5xh/5/

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and code snippet, this is exactly what I was looking for!